# Как узнать время сервера из присланного ответа POST запроса?

Tags: java, android, http, post, время

Как вытащить время сервера из ответа, который пришел на POST запрос? 
Для отправки POST запроса с Android используется библиотека OKHTTP.

```
String post(String...url) throws IOException {
        FormEncodingBuilder form = new FormEncodingBuilder();
        RequestBody formBody =form.build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Cookie", x)
                .url(url[0])
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В `Response` есть параметр `Date`, в котором передается текущее время сервера.

Пример **Response Headers**:

```
Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2015 23:24:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Но в вашем методе `post()` возвращается только `body`, тогда как `Date` хранится в `headers`.

Соответственно пример кода для получения даты:

```
Date post(String...url) throws IOException {
        FormEncodingBuilder form = new FormEncodingBuilder();
        RequestBody formBody =form.build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Cookie", x)
                .url(url[0])
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        //return response.body().string(); //Возвращается только Body.
        return response.headers().getDate("Date"); //Возвращаем объект Date.
}
```

Comment: Можно код, как его достать? в unix варианте если можна.

Comment: Добавил пример. В Date по умолчанию unix формат.

Comment: Хм, в logcat код возвращает строку "Sat Nov 14 19:30:25 GMT+05:00 2015", как быть?)

Comment: Из объекта Date можно получить отдельно время: `date.getTime();`
Для unix: `date.getTime() / 1000;`