# Получить время UTC без связи с временем устройства android

Tags: android, utc

Я знаю что можно получить время UTC используя такую конструкцию:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
```

и так мы получим время в секундах. Все вроде бы хорошо, но есть одна проблема - я так получаю время устройства в секундах. А если например у меня на устройстве время настроено неправильно, и тогда я получаю время не правильно. Вопрос - можно ли как-то получать utc время отдельно от времени устройства? Или его можно взять только с сети отдельно от времени устройства?

### UPDATE

чисто как вариант можно попробовать с gps time, может получится.

Comment: Есть такой вариант: [Как узнать время сервера из присланного ответа POST запроса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/466243/11515). То есть берём время сервера из заголовков ответа, сравниваем с системным и учитываем разницу при дальнейших расчётах.

Answer (score 1):

System.currentTimeMillis() не может вернуть неправильное время, этот метод возвращает число миллисекунд прошедших с 1 января 1970 года 00:00 по Гринвичу. Вы вполне можете его использовать.

Comment: да, но если я переведу время на устройстве, то и число миллисекунд будет больше, а меня интересует получение этого числа независимо от того правильное время стоит на устройстве или нет

Comment: Что значит "время стоит правильно"? В нужном часовом поясе?

Comment: да, вот к примеру у вас в вашем часовом поясе сейчас 8 утра, а вы перевели на 8 вечера, тогда кол-во мс будет больше, а меня интересует способ который будет игнорировать перевод времени и все-равно получать правильное кол-во мс, если он есть конечно :)

Comment: Наш метод возвращает число миллисекунд независимо от часового пояса, по Гринвичу, то есть с UTC+0, перевод часов на это никак не повлияет.

Comment: я проверил, и он зависит от времени установленного на устройстве, этот метод тянет время с устройства я так понимаю

Comment: может быть, число миллисекунд было разным, потому что вы вызывали метод в разные промежутки времени, уже пошло n миллисекунд?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90981/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and--).